# What exactly is the difference between these two statements

Tags: java, memory

I am a beginner in java and i was going through this code

```
    ListNode current = new ListNode();
    current = front;
```

and

```
    ListNode current = front;
```

Arent both set of statements creating a new object or is it that the memory is being reserved only for the first staement andfor the second only a vatriable is getting declared which holds the memory of the fron node?

Comment: The answers are correct but if you're new to Java you can basically think of a reference as a pointer (it isn't, but it is pretty close). The first call created a new object and assigns current to it, you then assign the current pointer to the front object losing your previous reference. The answer below is clear, but I find the "pointer logic" if you're coming from another language to be a good analogy (not the same, but close enough to think about).

Comment: There is a belief (I see it more in Objective-C than Java) that when you declare a reference to an object you need to "allocate" or "create" the object before you can assign anything to the reference.  This belief leads to sequences such as the above (which are a good sign that the author had a poor grasp of the basic concepts of the language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListNode current = new ListNode();
current = front;
```

This creates a new `ListNode` and assigns it to `current`. It then immediately overwrites that reference, losing the reference to the new object. This is almost certainly a mistake. The code is equivalent to

```
new ListNode();
ListNode current = front;
```

If the `ListNode()` constructor has no side effects, that first statement is useless, and could just be

```
ListNode current = front;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement actually creates a new object (which will be garbage collected soon after because `current` points to another object in the next instruction), whereas the second one only creates a reference to an existing object.

The recommended code is the second one because the `ListNode` created in the first one is never used so it is useless to instantiate it.